# error: 'high_resolution_clock' has not been declared

Tags: c++, time, c++-chrono, high-resolution-clock

I am using g++ version 8.1.0 on windows 10 but still when I try to compile

```
auto start=high_resolution_clock::now();
rd(n);
auto stop=high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start);
cout<<duration.count()<<endl;
```

I get the error as

```
error: 'high_resolution_clock' has not been declared
 auto start=high_resolution_clock::now();
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I have included both chrono and time.h

Comment: `high_resolution_clock` --> `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the `std::chrono::` namespace qualifier in front of `high_resolution_clock`, `microseconds`, and `duration_cast`, eg:

```cpp
#include <chrono>

auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
rd(n);
auto stop = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(stop-start);
std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
```

Otherwise, you can use `using` statements instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono;

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
rd(n);
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start);
std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
```

or:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::microseconds;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;

auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
rd(n);
auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop-start);
std::cout << duration.count() << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I just got the solution,
I forgot to use the chrono namespace
so the code should be:

```
auto start=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
rd(n);
auto stop=chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
auto duration = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::microseconds>(stop-start);
cout<<duration.count()<<endl;
```